# Set Link On Admin Menu Grid values in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

I want to add link in Custom Menu Grid values, so for achieving this I add a class in my layout file and in the class file i do this following

```
<?php

namespace Feedback\Addon\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;

class UserEmail extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) 
        {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('email');
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) 
            {
                if (isset($item['email'])) 
                {
                    $path = $this->context->getUrl('customer/index/edit/',['id'=>244]);

                    $url = "<a = '".$path."'>".$item['email']."</a>";


                    $item['email'] = '<a href="'.$this->context->getUrl('customer/index/edit/',['id' => 224]).'">'.$item['email'].'</a>';

                    $item[$name] = html_entity_decode('<a href="'.$this->urlBuilder->getUrl(self::PRODUCT_URL_PATH_EDIT, ['id' => $item['product_id']]).'">'.$item['product_id'].'</a>');
                }
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

it will return the  tag not the link, so please tell me what should I do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to pass array to make it work that include **href** and **label**

```
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) 
        {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) 
            {
                if (isset($item['email'])) 
                {

                   $item[$fieldName]['email'] = [
                        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('customer/index/edit/', ['id' => $item['entity_id']]),
                        'label' => __($item['email'])
                    ];



                }
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
```